# used in layered naviation (Filterable with results) stopped showing comparable attributes on frontend

Tags: magento-1.9

For the product with a attribute which is used in layer navigation = 'Filterable with results' Suddenly stopped showing attributes to filter on frontend. How to check this ? where should i lookup ?

Comment: are u using any extension for this layered navigation.or default magento navigation

Comment: @PradeepSanku No, i'm using default magento navigation.

Answer (score 2):

Just Check following for a attribute to be seen in the layered navigation

1) Attribute's `Catalog Input Type for Store Owner` should be `Dropdown`.

2) `Use In Layered Navigation` should be `Yes`

3) if everything is above is their.now go to cache and clear the cache.

Comment: 1) yes. 2) yes 3) cleared and tested. It's not showing up. did i mess core files ? This core functionality isn't working :(

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't quite clear on exactly what happened. Did a specific attribute disappear from the layered navigation (i.e. the filters), or did the layered navigation disappear altogether?

The visibility of the layered navigation depends on the category. Unless you've changed the layout, you should find that layered navigation appears in the search results page, and in categories where "Is Anchor" is set to "Yes". So if there are no filters at all, perhaps you need to set "Is Anchor" on your category.

To my knowledge, the layered navigation doesn't appear anywhere else - home page, product page, account pages, cart/checkout - because it just wouldn't make any sense. Well maybe on the home page, it could act as a filter against all products, but AFAIK it doesn't do that.

On the other hand, if just one attribute has disappeared from the layered navigation, it might just be because that attribute isn't relevant to the contents of that category. If you set an attribute as "filterable (with results)", Magento will only show that attribute in the filters if it's applicable to the products listed. Whereas if you set it "filterable (no results)" it will appear as a filter whether relevant or not.